# Discord OAuth2 doesn't give email

Tags: php, oauth-2.0, discord

Upon succeeding OAuth via Discord, some of my users are reporting not being able to signup to my WebApp.

After further investigation, I found out that in some cases (often), Discord sent `null` instead of a user's actual email in the response. I've used the identify+email scope.

Any idea why?

Example response:

```
{"id":"****************","username":"*******","avatar":null,"discriminator":"****","email":null,"verified":false,"locale":"en-US","mfa_enabled":false,"flags":0}
```

Comment: Could be because of the fact that he is unverified. I'd suggest to contact them directly to understand what happens here.

Comment: @NoahBoegli might be true, but why would Discord provide the "verified" key then? Does Discord allow signing up without an email?

Comment: I've found [this article](https://www.bleepingcomputer.com/forums/t/695032/guests-cant-join-ourany-discord-server-anymore/) mentioning guest accounts which would explain why you sometimes have no-email and unverified (since there is no e-mail to verify).

Answer (score 6):

Late answer, but I hope it will be helpful for someone.
If the user has registered himself on discord but has not verified it's email, then this kind of issue occurs.

Comment: This should be a comment since I expect someone to check this before.

Comment: yes yes, but my reputation score did not allow me to write a comment, so this answer.